# Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{z}{i+2} \right)^n$

Tags: calculus, limits, complex-numbers, solution-verification

We wish to evaluate the following limit: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{z}{i+2} \right)^n$ where $z \in \mathbb{C}$ is a fixed value.

My solution is to let $z = r \mathrm{e}^{i\theta}$ and $i+2 = \sqrt{5}\mathrm{e}^{i\phi}$. Then the limit becomes:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{r}{\sqrt{5}} \right)^n \mathrm{e}^{ni(\theta - \phi)}$$
Obviously, the limit of the exponential component is not defined, but if $r < \sqrt{5}$, $(r/\sqrt{5})^n$ will approach zero as $n \to \infty$.

Hence my final answer is that the limit is divergent if $r \geq \sqrt{5}$, and converges to $0$ if $r < \sqrt{5}$.

Is this the correct method for solving a question of this style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument is fine, with the only caveat that you are missing the case where $r=\sqrt5$ and $\theta=\phi$.